# How do I create a translation repository for VS2008 when localizing WinForms?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, localization, repository

When I am writing translated strings into the form **`resx`** files in VS2008, is there anything like a translation repository? It was very helpful in my old C++ Builder times. This is what I did then and what I would like to accomplish in VS2008:

- Translate "Cancel" in one form to German "**`Abbrechnen`**"
- Add this translation to a repository, since this word is repeated in most forms
- When I start to translate another form, I just read all localized strings from the repository, so the common texts like "Cancel" are translated automatically.
- I manually change only those strings that were not found in the repository

Is there anything similar in VS2008?